# Meaning of "pdf, _ = " on website_sale controller Odoo 11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

What does "pdf, _ = ..." mean (Odoo 11) in this controller?

```
# odoo\addons\website_sale\controllers\main.py
@http.route(['/shop/print'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def print_saleorder(self):
    sale_order_id = request.session.get('sale_last_order_id')
    if sale_order_id:
        pdf, _ = request.env.ref('sale.action_report_saleorder').sudo().render_qweb_pdf([sale_order_id])
        pdfhttpheaders = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', u'%s' % len(pdf))]
        return request.make_response(pdf, headers=pdfhttpheaders)
    else:
        return request.redirect('/shop')
```

If I remove the " , _ " and leave only the variable "pdf = ...", the download of any report in Odoo website doesn't work.

I'd like to understand what it stands for.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you're calling returns a tuple, not a single value. The `pdf, _ =` is called tuple unpacking - it takes the (in this case two item) tuple's values and stores the first one in the first variable, and the second one in the second variable. So `pdf` gets set to the first element in the tuple, and `_` is set to the second.

The `_` isn't a special character or anything, it's just a convention for a variable you don't actually care about, but the syntax requires an identifier there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the expression returns a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) containing two elements. The `pdf, _ =` means unpack the tuple assigning the first value to `pdf` and the second value to `_`.

Among other [uses](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-the-underscore-of-python-309d1a029edc) underscore's are often used as variable names when you don't care about, or will not use, the contents of the variable but python requires an identifier.